# Changing the enrollment button for learnpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

I want to change the "Start Now" text to  Enroll now in learnpress plugin
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBsJS.png)

Comment: I saw that a lot of users tried to "translate" this button with a plugin called Loco. Maybe you can go with that ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ It looks as though you're trying to get someone to write code for you which is not what this website is for _ Please add any code attempt that you've tried. You should also visit SO Help Center 'Asking' section to find out more about submitting a properly formatted question >>> stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1):

The Coding of all WordPress plugins including the text and images are inside the plugin Folder "wp-content/plugins/".

A easy way to make change to the plugin is find the code line where "Start Now" is located, for this install [String Location](https://wordpress.org/plugins/string-locator/) and search "Start Now" string on the whole WordPress directory or just the plugin directory. Then you will find and edit the text with no problem.

With this trick you can change any plugin text or even theme css colors.